# Finding the region (district, state, etc.) of a given coordinate in GADM data (in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster

We are using the GADM data for France, and I'm curious if we can find the region of a point based on its latitude and longitude.

So I can plot a map of France using

```
library(raster)
fr = getData("GADM", country="FRA", level=1)
plot(fr)
```

The coordinates of a point in Paris is

```
latitude = 48.86122650866868
longitude = 2.341541835915652
```

Now when I look up different regions at level 1, I get

```
> fr$NAME_1
 [1] "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes"       "Bourgogne-Franche-Comté"    "Bretagne"                   "Centre-Val de Loire"       
 [5] "Corse"                      "Grand Est"                  "Hauts-de-France"            "Île-de-France"             
 [9] "Normandie"                  "Nouvelle-Aquitaine"         "Occitanie"                  "Pays de la Loire"          
[13] "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"
```

Is it possible to extract the region of that coordinate, which should be Île-de-France?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with package {sf}:

```
library(sf)

my_point <- st_point(c(2.3415, 48.86122))

## convert fr to class sf
fr <- st_as_sf(fr)

i <- st_within(my_point, fr)

fr[as.integer(i),]$NAME_1
```

output:

```
[1] "Île-de-France"
```

**edit** to check, map point and provinces with labels:

```
library(ggplot2)

## set coordinate reference system for my_point
## to EPSG 4326 (WGS84):
my_point <- st_sfc(my_point, crs = 4326)

fr %>%
ggplot(mapping = aes(geometry = geometry)) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = NAME_1)) +
  geom_sf(my_point, mapping = aes(geometry = geometry))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `geodata::gadm`. Then you would use "terra" instead of "raster" and do:

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
fr = gadm("France", level=1)

latitude = 48.86122650866868
longitude = 2.341541835915652
v <- vect(cbind(longitude, latitude))
extract( fr[,"NAME_1"], v)
extract( fr[,"NAME_1"], v)
#  id.y        NAME_1
#1    1 Île-de-France
```